# Polimorfismo com list comprehension em Haskell

Tags: haskell

Tenho essas duas funções:

```hs
sequenciaInt :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
sequenciaInt i j |j >= i = [i..j]
                 |otherwise = sequenciaInt j i

sequenciaChar :: Char -> Char -> [Char]
sequenciaChar i j |j >= i = [i..j]
                  |otherwise = sequenciaChar j i
```

Uma função retorna uma lista de `Int` e a outra uma lista de `Char`.

**É possível ter uma função genérica que retorna uma lista de `Int` ou `Char` dependendo do parâmetro passado (seja `Int` ou `Char`)?**

Algo do tipo:

```hs
sequencia :: a -> a -> [a]
sequencia i j |j >= i = [i..j]
              |otherwise = sequencia j i
```

Porém, esse código acima retorna erro:

```hs
main.hs:2:16: error:
    • No instance for (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘>=’
      Possible fix:
        add (Ord a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            sequencia :: forall a. a -> a -> [a]
    • In the expression: j >= i
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for ‘sequencia’:
        j >= i
      In an equation for ‘sequencia’:
          sequencia i j
            | j >= i = [i .. j]
            | otherwise = sequencia j i
  |
2 | sequencia i j |j >= i = [i..j]
  |                ^^^^^^
main.hs:2:25: error:
    • No instance for (Enum a)
        arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘i .. j’
      Possible fix:
        add (Enum a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            sequencia :: forall a. a -> a -> [a]
    • In the expression: [i .. j]
      In an equation for ‘sequencia’:
          sequencia i j
            | j >= i = [i .. j]
            | otherwise = sequencia j i
  |
2 | sequencia i j |j >= i = [i..j]
  |                         ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível e sua função está quase correta.

A sua implementação de `sequencia` usa o operador `>=` e o *açúcar sintático* `[i..j]`. 
Caso não saiba, açúcar sintático é uma sintaxe da própria linguagem que permite escrever alguma expressão de forma mais legível. Neste caso, a expressão `[i..j]` é substituída por, ou *desaçucarada* para `enumFromTo i j` antes do programa ser compilado. Portanto, `sequencia` exige que o tipo `a` de entrada pertença à classe `Ord` para que se possa usar `>=`, e à classe `Enum` para que `enumFromTo` esteja disponível.

Como você declarou `sequencia :: a -> a -> [a]` sem exigir classes específicas, o compilador reclama que nem todo `a` é possível, dizendo que não há garantias de que `a` seja `Ord` (primeiro erro) nem `Enum` (segundo erro).

Há duas soluções:

1. Reescrever a assinatura de tipo da função incluindo as restrições de classe, isto é,
   `sequencia :: (Ord a, Enum a) => a -> a -> [a]`, ou
2. Remover a assinatura completamente e deixar o compilador inferir o tipo corretamente.

Teste no GHCi e veja que ele não vai reclamar mais. O [Wikibook de Haskell (em português)](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Tipos_b%C3%A1sicos_II) talvez possa ajudar a entender restrições de classes.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o erro do meu código. Sou iniciante em Haskell, sua explicação e link são úteis.